# ASP.NET Forms Authentication - Return Auth Cookie with JSON response

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

I'm attempting to programmatically login to my own web application to do some screen scraping so I can run some automated tests.  Currently, when a user logs into the system, the following method is called:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) {
   // login logic -- ASP.NET Forms Authentication
   // do i need to send more back here? or change my return?
   return this.Json(new { resultText = "Success", ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
}
```

Is there some way for me to also return the information needed here so that the code that consumes the response can store that and then send it back with the subsequent request?

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(loginUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
// login request comes back successful

HttpWebResponse httpResponse = request .GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
// read authentication info here from response

HttpWebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create(pageUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
// include authentication info here
```

... or am I taking the wrong approach completely?